# boost::shared_ptr<const T> to boost::shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, boost, casting, constants, shared-ptr

I want to cast the const-ness out of a `boost::shared_ptr`, but I `boost::const_pointer_cast` is not the answer.  `boost::const_pointer_cast` wants a `const boost::shared_ptr<T>`, not a `boost::shared_ptr<const T>`.  Let's forego the obligatory "you shouldn't be doing that".  I know... but I need to do it... so what's the best/easiest way to do it?

For clarity sake:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const T> orig_ptr( new T() );

boost::shared_ptr<T> new_ptr = magic_incantation(orig_ptr);
```

I need to know the magic_incantation()

Answer (score 9):

`boost::const_pointer_cast` *is* the function you want to use:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const int> ci(new int(42));
boost::shared_ptr<int> i(boost::const_pointer_cast<int>(ci));
```

Does that not work for you?  I tested that with both Boost 1.43 and the Visual C++2010 C++0x implementation--no issues with either.

Comment: Actually... it did work for me when I specified the template parameter.  For some reason when I did it the first time I didn't use it and was then fooled by the compiler's error message.  Thanks.

Comment: @Flevine:  Yeah, `const_pointer_cast`, like the C++ `const_cast`, can add or remove both const and volatile qualifiers, so the desired target qualification isn't known without specifying it.  I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Note that other "shareholders" will be very *surprised*, to say the least, if a shared `const T` suddenly changes...